# Python - reading comments in xlsx

Tags: python, xlsx

Is there any way to read comments in xlsx files using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[openpyxl](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/) enables the manipulation of xlsx files and there is discussion here of adding the ability to access comments.  If this does not work the comments for a given xlsx file can be accessed in xml format by renaming and unzipping the xlsx file as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/openpyxl-users/QkpSSL8yrcQ).  This xml file can then be read by python.

Comment: Is there any modified version of openpyxl who can read comments? or need I to do it separately?